# Default music player restarting song on Bluetooth reconnect

Tags: media-player, bluetooth-audio

When my s4 mini pairs with my car stereo, the headset can control operation of the music layer ok, except when I turn off the car then turn it back on, it has restarted the currently playing song, not paused/resumed.

I have tried different apps - pixel player, double twist and others, to no avail. The others all have issues where they don't receive Bluetooth commands as well as the default player or don't show the correct track info onscreen.

Is there a way to either get the default player to pause on disconnect and resume on reconnect or use a different app that will do the same?

Also, are there any apps to monitor what is going on under the hood with Bluetooth commands and which apps they are being routed to?

I am using a non rooted s4 mini, android 4.4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, poweramp works well when Bluetooth is reconnected. It has got a trial version from the playstore which you can install for testing, if it works then you can purchase it as per your requirements.

Here is the link for [Poweramp Music Player Trial version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer) in the Playstore.

The settings which you need to change is indicated in yellow color.

[image: screenshot]

<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>